# The meaning of "information shortcut" in this text?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Brewer and his colleagues identify generalized trust in other nations,
>   or international trust, as a key component of public opinion about
>   world aﬀairs (Brewer 2004; Brewer et al. 2004; Brewer, Aday, and Gross
>   2005). Tey defne this form of trust as follows:
>
> International trust [is] a generalized belief about whether most
>   foreign countries behave in accordance with normative expectations
>   regarding the conduct of nations. Citizens with high levels of
>   international trust see the realm of world aﬀairs as a friendly
>   environment where trust and cooperation among nations are the norms;
>   in contrast, citizens with low levels of international trust see the
>   same realm as a hostile environment where all nations strive against
>   one another for advantage and readily defect from cooperative eﬀorts.
>   Put another way, international trust is a standing decision to give
>   other nations the beneft of the doubt, an assumption that most
>   countries are of good will and benign intentions. (Brewer et al. 2004,
>   96)
>
> Brewer and his colleagues conceptualize this “standing decision”
>   as a cognitive heuristic, or **information shortcut**, comparing it to
>   both social trust (or interpersonal trust) and political trust (or
>   trust in government). Te former, a generalized belief that one can
>   trust strangers (Uslaner 2002), provides individuals with a
>   “standing decision to give most people—even those whom one does not know from direct experience—the beneft of the doubt” (Rahn and
>   Transue 1998, 545). Te latter, a generalized orientation toward
>   government based on normative expectations of its operation, likewise
>   oﬀers individuals “a simple decision rule” for deciding how much
>   beneft of the doubt to give government (Hetherington and Globetti
>   2002, 254).

I couldn't find the phrase "information shortcut" in the main dictionaries online. What is its meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context it indicates a ["rule of thumb"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thumb) which is used as an alternative to undertaking a longer analysis of the available information. A [shortcut](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shortcut) is an alternative to a longer standard route.

In this instance, it fits - as claimed - with the definition of [heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic) as an alternative and possibly sub-optimal but useful and often quicker knowledge discovery technique.